# New Relic availability alert

Tags: newrelic

I tried setting up an APM Availability alert but apparently is not supported in New Relic Alerts(beta) as shown here:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts-beta/getting-started/known-limitations-new-relic-alerts

How can I do the same using new Alerts?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [Synthetics](http://newrelic.com/synthetics) (a Ping monitor to be specific) paired with the Alerts(beta) to replicate the functionality of Availability Monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Although an 'app not reporting' alert condition is not built into New Relic Alerts, it's possible to rig one using NRQL alerts. Here are the steps:

1. Go to New Relic Alerts and begin creating a NRQL alert condition:

   - [NRQL alert conditions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts/defining-conditions/create-alert-conditions-nrql-queries)
2. Query your app with:

   - `SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction WHERE appName = 'foo'`
3. Set your threshold to :

   - Static
   - `sum of query results is below x`
   - `at least once in y minutes`

The query runs once per minute. If the app stops reporting then `count` will turn the `null` values into `0` and then we `sum` them. When the number goes below whatever your threshold is then you get a notification. I recommend using the preview graph to determine how low you want your transactions to get before receiving a notification. Here's some good information:

- [Relic Solution: NRQL alerting with “sum of the query results”](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-nrql-alerting-with-sum-of-the-query-results/52431)